# Pitch and Yaw on a 2D ImagePlus object

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation, 3d

I am using a service , which when given a human face, returns the "roll" "yaw" and "pitch" values.

I have the picture as an ImagePlus object with Java. I used the rotate() function with ImageProcessor() instance of the ImagePlus object to simulate the "roll" measurment returned by the service. However, since I am using a 2D graphic, is there anyway I can use the "pitch" and "yaw" measurments to better simulate the picture?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "roll", "pitch" and "yaw" have the same meaning as in flight dynamics. Then you can simulate effects of "pitch" and "yaw" by applying vertical and horisontal perspective corrections. The simpest form is to map a rectangle to a trapezium:

```
 ________          ____________
|        |         \          /
|        |  ==>     \        /
|        |           \      /
|________|            \____/
```

You mention `ImagePlus` object, so I conclude that you are programming with ImageJ. In this case you can look how to implement perspective correction in the source code of its [Perspective correction](http://pacific.mpi-cbg.de/wiki/index.php/Interactive_Perspective) plugin.